# What the best practice to bind an event to a tag element? Writing the event in the tag or binding it from javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, mouseevent

My question it's general, but what about in case I'm using Angular 2 framework?
Eg.:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Let's say I have this kind of template, and I have to insert CLICK event on each li of the ul. What's the best to do?

```
<li (click)="myFn($event)">
```

or

```
<ul (click)="myFn($event.target)">
```

or binding from the class/js?

Comment: `(click)="myFn($event)"` is the Angular2 way to do it. If you use `*ngFor` to create the `<li>` elements, you won't have to add `(click)="..."` multiple times - which I think is the common case.

Comment: Yes, but I could do also `<ul (click)="myFn($event.target)">`

Comment: You could also do something entirely different :D You didn't explain what your requirements are. There are different ways of doing things and there is a use case for most of them. In one case one way is better, in another case the other way might be a better fit.

Comment: I wanted to know what's the best practice, and if binding the event from javascript, what your solution(s) would be.

Comment: Binding from JS is in general against best practice. It's your call if you think binding from JS is the better approach for a specific use case you might have.

Comment: Can you write also why it's a best practice?
Thanks

Comment: Because this way Angular takes care of removing the event handler when the component is destroyed. It prevents direct DOM access. It's usually easier to understand and makes the code easier to read because it's the standard way of doing it in Angular.